# Website won't load(waiting forever), others will

Tags: website

I'm facing a strange issue.Following is the website that trying to visit

```
http://forum.xda-developers.com/
```

while eneters the url in any browser it's keep loading forever tried in `CHROME`,`FIREFOX` and `IE`.

I can `ping` to `forum.xda-developers.com`
[image]

able to visit other websites,and i have checked nothing configured in `windows host file`

OS: Windows XP

Comment: The site might be down, but the server still up. Nothing special about that, happens quite some times.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid no your are absolutely wrong. it can be access and i do check that website on my `mobile`, yourself try you can also access